# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B - No Display, But Steady Lights

Tags: boot, pi-2, display

I am using a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with NOOBS on an SD Card. When I plug in the power supply, the red and green lights turn on. The lights maintain a steady glow and are very bright. Then I plug in the HDMI Cable to my monitor (display) and nothing happens. My desktop does not detect any signal and just switches to another display source. It has a blank screen and nothing happens. Please help. I need to get this up and running right away.

EDIT: Just to make it clearer, the GREEN and RED LED Lights are on at a steady pace, not blinking or anything.

Comment: Have you tried starting it with the HDMI cable connected IIRC without the HDMI connected at startup it defaults to the composite video output. What do you mean by plug it into your desktop?

Comment: @SteveRobillard - I meant plugging in the HDMI cable from my RasPi to my display monitor. So, are you trying to say that there is no display/only a black screen because the RasPi is set to default to display as a composite video and not HDMI?

Comment: it is when no hdmi is connected on bootup

Comment: Did you use SDFormatter to wipe the micro SD first?

Comment: @DSlee that is not likley the problem as both the red and green leds are on.